# Slow PDF render with PyQt from MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyqt

Until yesterday, I was using SQLite for my application. Today I found a reason strong enough (multiple instances of application) to switch to MySQL using `pymysql`.

At one point, my application queries the database for 300 rows:

```
cur.execute('select ime,brPredmeta,statusStr,sudskiBr ,sudija ,datumRasprave,statusPredmeta, zaduzen,datumZaduzenja from predmeti')
sviaktivni = cur.fetchall()
sviaktivni = list(sviaktivni) #make a list of tuples
sviaktivni.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0)) #sort the list
```

After that, I extract the variables and then use those variables to make a HTML document, which is then sent to printer (PDF or regular printer). Code for generating HTML is pretty simple; table with few rows for "header" (omitted here for clarity), then another table for "body" with code like this:

```
#extract the variables
for tuple in sviaktivni:
    ime,brPredmeta,statusStr,sudskiBr ,sudija ,datumRasprave,statusPredmeta, zaduzen,datumZaduzenja = tuple
#done extracting

  body = ('<html><head><title></title>'
    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'
    '<style></style>'
    '</head>'
    '<body>'
    '<table align ="center" border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed">'
    '<tr height="10%">'
    '<td align="left" width="20">'+str(brojac)+'.</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="180">'+ime+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="100">'+str(brPredmeta)+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="80">'+statusStr+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="80">'+str(sudskiBr)+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="140">'+sudija+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="150">'+zaduzen+'</td>'
    '<td align="left">'+datumZaduzenja+'</td>'
    '<td align="right"> '+statusPredmeta+' </td>'
    '</tr>'
    '</table>'
    '</body>'
    '</html>')

  self.ui.printHTML.append(body)
```

My problem is that the query is executed instantly, but after that CPU is stuck at 100%, and the whole program just freezes. Print preview dialog is sometimes shown with data, sometimes it's just an empty window. Either way, whole app is frozen.

There were no problems with the same code using SQLite. What should I do? Get back to sqlite and risk database corruption?

Comment: And, last but not least: Why pymysql and not a native library?

Comment: Let me first thank you for showing interest in solving my problems. Secondly, I need a little time to process your answers and questions :) `pymysql` is used because I'm developing in python3, which doesn't support mysqldb (as far as i know).

Comment: Ah, okay. Briefly looking at the code there seems to indicate that it may be the cause of your pain in this case, but I am far from certain.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just load the whole SQL result into memory, and expect this to work for all cases. Moreover, use the database to do the sorting for you, that's what it is good at.

Simply loop over the cursor and process results one by one, that way you don't have to fill up memory with intermediate results:

```
cur.execute('''
    select 
        ime, brPredmeta, statusStr, sudskiBr, sudija,
        datumRasprave,statusPredmeta, zaduzen,datumZaduzenja
    from predmeti
    order by ime
    ''')
for row in cur:
    ime, brPredmeta, statusStr, sudskiBr, sudija, datumRasprave, statusPredmeta, zaduzen, datumZaduzenja = row
    # Process row data.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same thing with your code. It seems that freezing is not MySQL related (or is it), but PDF related. If I print(row) all the rows get printed to console with lightning speed. PDF creation may be the cause of freezing, and large amount of HTML (300 rows currently).

Comment: Right, so SQLite is not going to help matters there either. If things *do* work with SQLite, then that's because SQLite needs less memory than a MySQL process. Move the MySQL server to another machine and things *could* work again, except you cannot know if your end-users will have enough memory available. :-P You now have a different problem to solve.

Comment: My advice: make a new question stating what you are doing (load rows from a database, generate HTML to end up in a PDF), your problem (with 150/200/whatever items CPU spikes to 100% and everything locks up). Perhaps someone can help. Include details on how the PDF thing works (is it a pyqt function?).

Comment: My PC is not that shabby, i3 with 8GB of RAM etc. I will tweak MySQL config a little, maybe that'll help.

Comment: Also see [Is there a better layout language than HTML for printing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/458340)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the SQLite Docs...

> Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same
>   application access a single database file at the same time?
>
> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time.
>   Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only
>   one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in
>   time, however.
>
> SQLite uses reader/writer locks to control access to the database.
>   (Under Win95/98/ME which lacks support for reader/writer locks, a
>   probabilistic simulation is used instead.) But use caution: this
>   locking mechanism might not work correctly if the database file is
>   kept on an NFS filesystem. This is because fcntl() file locking is
>   broken on many NFS implementations. You should avoid putting SQLite
>   database files on NFS if multiple processes might try to access the
>   file at the same time. On Windows, Microsoft's documentation says that
>   locking may not work under FAT filesystems if you are not running the
>   Share.exe daemon. People who have a lot of experience with Windows
>   tell me that file locking of network files is very buggy and is not
>   dependable. If what they say is true, sharing an SQLite database
>   between two or more Windows machines might cause unexpected problems.
>
> We are aware of no other embedded SQL database engine that supports as
>   much concurrency as SQLite. SQLite allows multiple processes to have
>   the database file open at once, and for multiple processes to read the
>   database at once. When any process wants to write, it must lock the
>   entire database file for the duration of its update. But that normally
>   only takes a few milliseconds. Other processes just wait on the writer
>   to finish then continue about their business. Other embedded SQL
>   database engines typically only allow a single process to connect to
>   the database at once.
>
> However, client/server database engines (such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, or
>   Oracle) usually support a higher level of concurrency and allow
>   multiple processes to be writing to the same database at the same
>   time. This is possible in a client/server database because there is
>   always a single well-controlled server process available to coordinate
>   access. If your application has a need for a lot of concurrency, then
>   you should consider using a client/server database. But experience
>   suggests that most applications need much less concurrency than their
>   designers imagine.
>
> When SQLite tries to access a file that is locked by another process,
>   the default behavior is to return SQLITE_BUSY. You can adjust this
>   behavior from C code using the sqlite3_busy_handler() or
>   sqlite3_busy_timeout() API functions.

Comment: Thank you Martin, but I was aware of that.

Before I switched to MySQL, multiple instances of the same application were running with SQLite, over LAN. Only problem was the speed, or latency perhaps.

Other than that, multiple users here on SO suggested that SQLite database used over LAN will eventually fail and get corrupted. That is the main reason I tried MySQL.

Maybe this one is "solved", and I will open up another question.