# SQLite over LAN

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

my application uses SQLite database for it's data storage. Idelly, this database should reside on some network drive, let's name it Z: (Windows XP's "Map network drive" feature).

Application is being developed under Linux, with database locally stored. Here is a part of one module:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect("base.db")
```

What would be the correct way to access database on Z: drive? Something along the lines of:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import os

path = 'Z:\'
con = lite.connect(path+"base.db")
```

Comment: Note that storing *any* database format on a shared drive and expecting this to be performant and reliable when accessed by *multiple processes* is going to lead to disappointment. Most likely your SQLite database will end up corrupted, and you should look at a client-server capable database instead. If your app is not going to access the SQLite database from mulitple processes, you'll *probably* be okay.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that issue. I have tried to use MySql instead, but other problems appeared, as I described here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260623/slow-pdf-render-with-pyqt-from-mysql-query/12260840)

Comment: From that question I deduce that you do want to use your SQLite db from multiple processes. You **will** end up with a corrupted database. I'm sure there is a solution to your MySQL problem, and if not, switch to a *different* client-server-capable database such as PostgreSQL instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `os.path.join` to create your path, since it will use the correct path seperator. Also, you can use `os.name` to check if you're running on windows:

```
filename = 'base.db'

path = os.path.join('z:/', filename) if os.name == 'nt' else filename

con = lite.connect(path)
```

Nonetheless, you probably want to make the file location configurable to make it easier to develop/debug/deploy your application.